# Alpakka - read Kryo-serialized objects from S3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, kryo, alpakka

I have Kryo-serialized binary data stored on S3 (thousands of serialized objects).

*Alpakka* allows to read the content as `data: Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`. But Kryo format doesn't use delimiters so I can't split each serialized object into a separate `ByteString` using `data.via(Framing.delimiter(...))`.

So, Kryo actually needs to read the data to understand when an object ends, and it doesn't look streaming-friendly.

Is it possible to implement this case in streaming fashion so that I get `Source[MyObject, NotUsed]` in the end of the day?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph stage that does that. It handles the case when a serialized object spans two byte strings. It needs to be improved when objects are large (not my use case) and can take more than two byte strings in `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`.

```
object KryoReadStage {
  def flow[T](kryoSupport: KryoSupport,
              `class`: Class[T],
              serializer: Serializer[_]): Flow[ByteString, immutable.Seq[T], NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(new KryoReadStage[T](kryoSupport, `class`, serializer))
}

final class KryoReadStage[T](kryoSupport: KryoSupport,
                             `class`: Class[T],
                             serializer: Serializer[_])
  extends GraphStage[FlowShape[ByteString, immutable.Seq[T]]] {

  override def shape: FlowShape[ByteString, immutable.Seq[T]] = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = {
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

      setHandler(in, new InHandler {

        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val bytes =
            if (previousBytes.length == 0) grab(in)
            else ByteString.fromArrayUnsafe(previousBytes) ++ grab(in)

          Managed(new Input(new ByteBufferBackedInputStream(bytes.asByteBuffer))) { input =>
            var position = 0
            val acc = ListBuffer[T]()

            kryoSupport.withKryo { kryo =>
              var last = false

              while (!last && !input.eof()) {
                tryRead(kryo, input) match {
                  case Some(t) =>
                    acc += t
                    position = input.total().toInt
                    previousBytes = EmptyArray
                  case None =>
                    val bytesLeft = new Array[Byte](bytes.length - position)

                    val bb = bytes.asByteBuffer
                    bb.position(position)
                    bb.get(bytesLeft)

                    last = true
                    previousBytes = bytesLeft
                }
              }

              push(out, acc.toList)
            }
          }
        }

        private def tryRead(kryo: Kryo, input: Input): Option[T] =
          try {
            Some(kryo.readObject(input, `class`, serializer))
          } catch {
            case _: KryoException => None
          }

      })

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          pull(in)
        }
      })

      private val EmptyArray: Array[Byte] = Array.empty

      private var previousBytes: Array[Byte] = EmptyArray

    }
  }

  override def toString: String = "KryoReadStage"

  private lazy val in: Inlet[ByteString] = Inlet("KryoReadStage.in")
  private lazy val out: Outlet[immutable.Seq[T]] = Outlet("KryoReadStage.out")

}
```

**Example usage**:

```
client.download(BucketName, key)
  .via(KryoReadStage.flow(kryoSupport, `class`, serializer))
  .flatMapConcat(Source(_))
```

**It uses some additional helpers below**.

*ByteBufferBackedInputStream*:

```
class ByteBufferBackedInputStream(buf: ByteBuffer) extends InputStream {

  override def read: Int = {
    if (!buf.hasRemaining) -1
    else buf.get & 0xFF
  }

  override def read(bytes: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int): Int = {
    if (!buf.hasRemaining) -1
    else {
      val read = Math.min(len, buf.remaining)
      buf.get(bytes, off, read)
      read
    }
  }

}
```

*Managed*:

```
object Managed {

  type AutoCloseableView[T] = T => AutoCloseable

  def apply[T: AutoCloseableView, V](resource: T)(op: T => V): V =
    try {
      op(resource)
    } finally {
      resource.close()
    }
}
```

*KryoSupport*:

```
trait KryoSupport {
  def withKryo[T](f: Kryo => T): T
}

class PooledKryoSupport(serializers: (Class[_], Serializer[_])*) extends KryoSupport {

  override def withKryo[T](f: Kryo => T): T = {
    pool.run(new KryoCallback[T] {
      override def execute(kryo: Kryo): T = f(kryo)
    })
  }

  private val pool = {
    val factory = new KryoFactory() {
      override def create(): Kryo = {
        val kryo = new Kryo

        (KryoSupport.ScalaSerializers ++ serializers).foreach {
          case ((clazz, serializer)) =>
            kryo.register(clazz, serializer)
        }

        kryo
      }
    }

    new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build()
  }

}
```